# How to set datetime index frequency in workdays time series pandas

Tags: datetime, indexing, time, series, frequency

When dealing with a time series pandas dataframe with date index (working days from Monday to Friday), I tried to change the index frequency from None to 'D' for daily time series. I got the following error:
ValueError: Inferred frequency None from passed values does not conform to passed frequency D

This is how my dataframe looks like:
[image]

And this is my code for setting the frequency:

```
df.index.freq = 'D'
```

Comment: Are there any null values for Date?

Comment: You may also want to try the asfreq method: df.asfreq. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df = df.asfreq('B')`

'B' stands for business day frequency (Mon-Fri).